# Como implementar Swipe To Refresh na WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

Quero implementar o Swipe To Refresh em minha WebView, isso é possível?
Eu sei que tem o Pull To Refresh mas não estou podendo baixar complementos (dependências) no momento.
Eu pesquisei bastante na internet e encontrei algo tipo esse:

```
browser.loadUrl("http://urlaqui");
swipeView.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,android.R.color.holo_blue_light, android.R.color.holo_green_light,android.R.color.holo_green_dark);
swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() 
{
@Override
public void onRefresh() 
{
        swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
             ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{
@Override
public void run() 
{
                         swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
browser.loadUrl("http://não-atualizar-somente-esta-url");
}
}, 4000);
}
});
}
```

Neste caso, quando o usuário atualizar, sempre vai voltar para a url especificada. Como faz para atualizar a página independente de qual url estiver?

Muito obrigado, agradeço desde já.

Comment: **webView.reload();** não resolve?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Olá amigo, muito obrigado por responder. Desculpe a pergunta, sou iniciante na programação, neste caso substituir: browser.loadUrl("site"); por webView.reload(); ?

Comment: Exato ! ao invés de chamar novamente a url chame o reload dentro do run!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Ok amigo, muito obrigado. Vou testar agora ;)

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Olá amigo, testei aqui e não funcionou. A app deu 'force close' :/ . Mas valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

1) Você pode utilizar o método **reload():**

```
browser.reload();
```

Mas tome cuidado, pois o reload apenas funciona se a requisição da página é via GET, este método não funciona com POST.

2) Você também pode utilizar o javascript para atualizar a página:

```
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true)");
```

3) Por último, você pode utilizar o exemplo que você descreveu sem precisar saber a URL, basta você pegar a URL atual que está no seu WebView.

```
browser.loadUrl(browser.getUrl().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando a ideia do amigo acima resolvi meu problema utilizando uma linha de javascript, fiz um variável int auxiliar e passei ela como parâmetro. ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView wv;
    SwipeRefreshLayout sp;
    int pegaUrl;

    //webview
    public void LoadWeb(){
        //start webview
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        //Enable JS
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setFocusable(true);
        wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        //Set Render Priority High
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);
        //Load URL
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.br");
        pegaUrl = 1;
        sp.setRefreshing(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                pegaUrl = 2;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                //hide the swipe refresh layout
                sp.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (wv.canGoBack()){
            wv.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sp = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.sp);
        sp.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                if (pegaUrl == 2) {
                    LoadWeb();
                    return;
                } else {
                    wv.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true)");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        LoadWeb();
    }
}
```

O código passa e tenta carregar a página, se não estiver conectado ele me envia para uma página de erro dizendo que o usuário não tem internet e no swipe to refresh ele refaz a verificação usando o return. Espero ter ajudado os próximos que poderão encontrar e resolver esse pequeno bug.